# Adding and Retrieving Image From SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-imageview

I created a table and database to store "title" "description" and "images use BLOB".But I can't retrieve image from SQLite database.I think my code is wrong.My Application shows new the description and images when click the next button. And Where I should keep all image in folder?

Class DatabaseHelper

```
void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  this.db = db;
  SQL_CREATE_WORD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            WordsContract.WordsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            WordsContract.WordsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_GROUP_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_NAME_WORD + " TEXT, " +
            WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_IMAGE + " BLOB " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_WORD_TABLE);

  fillWordsTable();

}
private void fillWordsTable() {
    Word f1 = new Word("FRUIT","Grapes","grape.png");
    addQuestion(f1);
    Word f2 = new Word("FRUIT","Longon","longon.png");
    addQuestion(f2);
}
private void addQuestion(Word word) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_GROUP_NAME,word.getGroup());
    cv.put(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_NAME_WORD,word.getNameWord());
    cv.put(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_IMAGE,word.getImage());
    db.insert(WordsContract.WordsTable.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
}
public List<Word> getAllWords(){
    List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ WordsContract.WordsTable.TABLE_NAME,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Word word = new Word();word.setNameWord(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_NAME_WORD)));
        word.setImage(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_IMAGE)));
            wordList.add(word);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return wordList; }
```

Class WordsContact

```
public static class WordsTable implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "word_questions";
    public static final String COLUMN_GROUP_NAME = "groups";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WORD = "words";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "images";
}
```

Class MainActivity

```
public void onCreate(){
   mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
   WordDbHelper dbHelper = new WordDbHelper(this);

   mWordList = dbHelper.getAllWords();

   wordCountTotal = mWordList.size();
   Collections.shuffle(mWordList);
showNextQuestion();}

public void showNextQuestion(){
     if(wordCounter < wordCountTotal){
        currentWord = mWordList.get(wordCounter);

        titleGroup.setText(currentWord.getGroup());
        nameWord.setText(currentWord.getNameWord());
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(currentWord.getImage());

        wordCounter++;

    }else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Bitmap

Comment: It's better to save image paths in database

Comment: You need to convert `currentWord.getImage()` to Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
 word.setImage(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_IMAGE)));
```

with:

```
word.setImage(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_IMAGE)));
```

and to load image:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( currentWord.getImage(), 
    0,currentWord.getImage().length));
```

Comment: I try but error    
 
word.setImage(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(WordsContract.WordsTable.COLUMN_IMAGE))); >>>  setImage
(java.lang.String)
in Word cannot be applied
to
(byte[])

Comment: or Word class { private String group; private String nameWord; public String image; } I try replace String to byte[] but  Word f1 = new Word("FRUIT","Grapes","grape.png"); >> error  
byte[]
"grape.png"  (java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

To store image in database, convert it into byte[]

```
public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

To store in database use this :

```
public void saveImageIntoDB(int id , Bitmap bitmap ) {


        byte[] imageBytes = getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap);

        insert.bindLong(1, id);
        insert.bindBlob(2, imageBytes);

        insert.executeInsert();
        insert.clearBindings() ;

    }
```

To retrieve from database :

```
public Bitmap retrieveImageFromDB(int i){

        String query = "select img  from table where imageid=" + i ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            byte[] imgByte = cursor.getBlob(0);
            cursor.close();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Add these in your db class

Comment: I put in DatabaseHelper class but error "Cannot resolve symbol 'insert' "